# How to access the class variable that available with in a class(Nested Class)

Tags: php

HI friends here I have share my code. I am used the Nested class in this Program. When I run this code it shows the Error like this. "**syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_FUNCTION**"

```
  class Nest
   {
  class Display
  { 
   private $s;
   public sum($a, $b)
 { 
   $s =$a+$b; 
 }
 function show()
 {
 echo "Sum of a and b is:: ". $s;
 }
 }
 }

 new $x = Nest::Display;
 $x->sum(12, 10);
 $x->show();
```

I don't know what mistake i did. Any one help to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you have to use nested classes? It seems 'smelly' to me.

Comment: starting here would be a good idea: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I not sure is PHP having a nested class? because I am searching on web lot of article comes to nested class with PHP but all those are forums .Same as nobody said PHP don't having a nested class.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have nested classes in PHP.

You may want to hear about [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) though.